# Product of expectations is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, random-walk

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and random variables $X_0, X_1, \ldots , X_n$ adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0}$. Assume furthermore that each $X_n$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$.

I want to deduce that if the $X_n$ have non-zero means, the variables 
\begin{align}
M_n = \prod_{k=0}^n \frac{X_k}{\mathbb{E}[X_k]} 
\end{align}
form a martingale. So,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n ] &= \mathbb{E}\big[ \prod_{k=0}^{n} \frac{X_k}{\mathbb{E}[X_k]} \cdot \frac{X_{n+1}}{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}]} \mid \mathcal{F}_n \big] \\
&= M_n \cdot \mathbb{E}\big[ \frac{X_{n+1}}{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}]} \mid \mathcal{F}_n \big] \\
&= M_n \cdot \mathbb{E}\big[ \frac{X_{n+1}}{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}]} \big].
\end{align}
I know that, in general, $\mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{A}] \big] = \mathbb{E}[X]$. But why is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[ \frac{X_{n+1}}{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}]} \big] = 1?
\end{align}
Is it possible to split the fraction, since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[ \frac{X_{n+1}}{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}]} \mid \mathcal{F}_n \big] =^? \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_n]}{\mathbb{E}\big[\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}] \mid \mathcal{F}_n] \big]} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} ]}{\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} ]} =1?
\end{align}

Comment: Pull the constant $1/\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}]$ out of the expectation.

Comment: Ok. That is obvious, so this is a trivial question.

Comment: Close? $ $ $ $ $ $